# ReportingTools in an Analysis of RNA-seq Data: GO analysis using GOstats gives an error

Tags: r, publish, bioconductor

I just followed the example given on page 5 of http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ReportingTools/inst/doc/rnaseqAnalysis.pdf

When executing le command line at the end of the page:
`publish(goResults, goReport, selectedIDs=selectedIDs, annotation.db="org.Mm.eg", pvalueCutoff= 0.05)`

I get the error:
*Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function 'keys' for signature '"character"'*

Previous examples of the PDF are working well.

I am using RStudio 1.1.463, R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) , on MacOS 10.14.6
Any help or guidance would be appreciated

Comment: Yes the mouse library org.Mm.eg.db is installed. That's how I could manage doing the previous commands in the cited document : 

des2Report <- HTMLReport(shortName ='RNAseq_analysis_with_DESeq2',  title ='RNA-seq analysis of differential expression using DESeq2', reportDirectory = "./reports")
publish(mockRna.dse,des2Report, pvalueCutoff=0.05, annotation.db="org.Mm.eg.db", factor = colData(mockRna.dse)$conditions, reportDir="./reports")> finish(des2Report)

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you provided to the function.. for example what is mockRna.dse? what did you provide for selectedIDs. Can you do dput(head(selectedIDs)) and paste that as your output

Comment: Here is what it gives:
> dput(head(selectedIDs))
c("258294", "108637", "383320", "71277", "71846", "72413")
The data are the one provided in the doc of the vignette for the Reporting tools.

Comment: information about mockRna.dse :
class: DESeqDataSet 
dim: 18760 6 
metadata(1): version
assays(4): counts mu H cooks
rownames(18760): 62915 100861788 ... 100035635 100504490
rowData names(22): baseMean baseVar ... deviance maxCooks
colnames(6): case1 case2 ... control2 control3
colData names(2): conditions sizeFactor

Comment: Maybe that's part of the problem? mockRna.dse is a deseq2 object and you passed it directly into publish(...) . You need to make a go term enrichment first

Comment: Sould I upgrade the R version to 3.6.1 ?

Comment: Does the example in the vignette works for you? If it does not, try upgrading. If it does, your code is the problem. I suspect it is the later. Like i said, there is a step missing from DESeq2 to GOstat result

Comment: Yes that is what I have done after in the last part of the script:
goParams <- new("GOHyperGParams", geneIds = selectedIDs, universeGeneIds = universeIDs, annotation ="org.Mm.eg" , ontology = "MF", pvalueCutoff = 0.01, conditional = TRUE, testDirection = "over")
goResults <- hyperGTest(goParams)
goReport <- HTMLReport(shortName ='go_analysis_rnaseq', title = "GO analysis of mockRnaSeqData", reportDirectory = "./reports")
publish(goResults, goReport, selectedIDs=selectedIDs, annotation.db="org.Mm.eg", pvalueCutoff= 0.05)
finish(goReport)

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf, sorry if I was not clear enougth. Up to now I have tested nothing but the exemples in the vignette. And this is where I encountered the first problems with the GO analysis at the command line :
publish(goResults, goReport, selectedIDs=selectedIDs, annotation.db="org.Mm.eg", pvalueCutoff= 0.05)
Of course I have run before the other code ines from the vignette. Hope this is more clear.

Comment: Hi @LaurenT, no worries, sorry I was also confused by all the information. Ok it works on my laptop and other PC. Both are on R 3.6.1, it might be that the vignette is meant for 3.6.1 since it was updated in 2019. Is it going to be a pain for you to upgrade?

Comment: That's it @StupidWolf, I did the 3.6.1 upgrade and now it is working !!
Nevertheless, it looks like I can not install DESeq, only DESeq2 on this version. Is it effectively the case or do I miss something ?
Thanks anyway StupidWolf

Comment: Yeah it should be DESeq2... DESeq was like almost 10 years ago..

Comment: I found a solution about installing packages. It was a permission issue. First, I identified where the packages were installed using `installed.packages()[, c("Package", "LibPath")]`. This outputs a list with the names and locations of the packages. Using this package location like /usr/lib/R/library, I changed the permission of these folders by `chmod -R 777` on the libraries folders. TThen I could do the package updates

Comment: cool.. does it work for you now?